# Show/Hide Function For an Embed

Tags: javascript, html

So I have 2 buttons, 1 for showing an embed and one for hiding an embed. They look like this:

```
<div class="button">
    <button class="btn-info" onclick="hide('myPdf')" type="button">HIDE</button>
</div>
<div class="button">
    <button class="btn-info" onclick="show('myPdf')" type="button">SHOW</button>
</div>
```

The JavaScript I use to show/hide is like this:

```
<script> 
            function show(target) {
                document.getElementById(target).style.visibility = 'visible';
            }

            function hide(target) {
                document.getElementById(target).style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
</script>
```

I want to have a single button which shows/hides on each click.

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<div class="button">
    <button class="btn-info" onclick="toggle('myPdf')" type="button">Toggle PDF</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script> 
        function toggle(target) {
            var curVal = document.getElementById(target).style.visibility;
            document.getElementById(target).style.visibility = (curVal === 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Good answer. Only one thing I would note, is that setting the `visibility` property doesn't collapse the target element, thus leaving a "hole" in the page :)

Comment: Good point. The same thing can be achieved by selecting and altering Element.style.display between none or block/inline/inline-block depending on what the OP wants to use. The code is almost identical.

Comment: @GeoffJames I am just using the same code OP did.  My goal is to show toggle implementation.  That is what he asked for

Comment: I understand that @HurricaneDevelopment. Obviously I don't know whether this is the behaviour that the OP is after - I was just merely making an observation :)

Answer (score 2):

### With jQuery

Nice and simply, you can do this with jQuery's `toggleClass()` function.

Just create a class that will hide the element you want to toggle, and toggle that class!

---

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fLg7mg5x/1/

Create a `.hidden` class in your CSS:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Then toggle it on the `click` event of your button:

```
$("#your-toggle-button").on("click", function() {
  $("#myPdf").toggleClass("hidden");
})
```

---

### With Vanilla JS

If you want to use Vanilla JS, you can do it this way:

Just create a `.hidden` class, like above (`display: none`) and then toggle that in your event handler:

```
<button onclick="showHide('myPdf')" type="button">
    Show/Hide
</button>
```

And then create a `function` in your JS to handle the click:

```
function showHide(target) {
  var targetElement = document.getElementById(target);
  targetElement.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle for the Vanilla JS solution: https://jsfiddle.net/yafmLrod/

---

### Visibility or Display?

Note the following:

- Setting `visibility` only changes the physical visibility of the element. Setting it to "hidden" *does not* collapse it from view - therefore leaving a space, where the element would normally be
- Setting `display` to `none` will collapse the element, and other elements below will move into the space it used to occupy - as if the element was never there

Depending on your choice, you can use the `.hidden` class for both scenarios:

**Visibility**

```
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

**Display**

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Choose wisely!

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Including jQuery to accomplish something that can be done with about 3 lines of vanilla JavaScript is not appropriate or recommended when the OP is not using jQuery nor did the OP tag jQuery in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @AlexanderGriffin I agree that you can do it with vanilla JS, but I've suggested it as an option for OP to consider - plus, using the `visibility` property, like @Hurricane's answer suggests will not collapse the target element, and leave a large "hole" in the page.

Comment: Then perhaps provide a solution in JavaScript that handles the 'hole' in the dom instead of recommending the inclusion of an entire library. Simply alter the Element.style.display property instead. That's a lot of unnecessary code!

Comment: @GeoffJames I never suggested it would collapse.  Not sure why you pulled me into this thread here...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AlexanderGriffin - I've updated my answer to include a Vanilla JS solution :) Sorry, Hurricane, I was just making an observation and giving justification for using the solution in my answer :)

Comment: Just as an extra note to this answer: given the OP's post including the `visibility` property. If you wanted to toggle the `visibility` instead - in the `.hidden` class, you could set the `visibility: hidden`, instead of the `display` property and toggle that, too. Both ways work the same :) *just be aware that `visibility` doesn't collapse the element and leaves a (no better word to describe it) "hole" in the page.